# Pop up menu inside overflow auto

Tags: html, css, menu

I've setup this [Codepen](https://codepen.io/isazulay/pen/GRWYprG). What I want is that the `menu` pops over the container. The `position: relative` is necessary. Is there a way to complete this.

Comment: please elaborate your question a bit, what does "menu pops over the container" implies in your context

Comment: @soraku02 as you see in the codepen the pop up menu stays inside the red container and shows an overflow auto. What I want is that the menu div pops over the container and is shown outside of it